# Will this importing structure be an issue (Circular Import)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a multi tenant react app. Therefore I have created a `config.ts` file (which holds all the configs) and a `getConfigs.ts` (which holds a function to retrieve the configs of a single tenant). This is fine, however sometimes **I need to have different components based on the tenant for which the app is build. Therefore I dynamically import inside my config some components. However, I think I might have an issue because components which I import inside my config file also rely on the config itself.** I am unsure if I can go forward with this structure I have created.

My imports look basically like this:

[image]

The `getConfigs.ts` exports a function which build the used config object.

```js
import { isEmpty, merge } from 'lodash';
import configs from './configs';

let cachedConfigs: typeof configs.default | {} = {};

const getConfigs = (client: keyof typeof configs, force = false) => {
  if (!isEmpty(cachedConfigs) && !force) {
    return cachedConfigs as typeof configs.default;
  }

  const defaultConfig = configs.default;
  const clientConfig = configs[client];

  const mergedConfig = merge(defaultConfig, clientConfig);

  cachedConfigs = mergedConfig;

  return mergedConfig as typeof configs.default;
};
```

The `configs.ts` exports an object of the following shape

```js
const configs = {
  default: {
    login: {
      layout: 'default'
    },
    component_a: {items: [{label: test}]}
  clientA: {
    login: {
      layout: 'custom'
      template: lazy(() => import($path_to_component_a))

    },
}
```

For instance in `componentA.tsx` I might do:

```js
const ComponentA = (props: any) => {
  const config = getConfigs(process.env.CURRENT_TENANT ?? 'default');
  const { items } = config.component_a;
  return (
    <div>
        {items?.map((item: any, index: number) => (
          <Button key={index} >
            {item.label}
          </Button>
        ))}

    </div>
  );
};
```

**This code is already working**, but I thought I have created a circular import here? Do I miss understand something? Is it a good idea to go forward with this idea or should I think of a different approach.

Comment: I think circular dependency matters only in compilation time, but you are using lazy loading so it's not a problem

Comment: @Konrad it also works if I directly import, is this becuase js is doing some magic to avoid the circular dependency?

Comment: I would not store a component in a config file anyway. E.g. store only an identifier for the template in the config, e.g. the path (or part of the path), and resolve that when needed. That way there also wouldn't a circular dependency (But I can't answer if the `lazy` safely breaks the circle.)

Comment: @kca valid point, however, we are using a self maintained component lib, which expects react nodes. If I now give a lib component the path to the lazy component which is my project then it fails. It seems that I cannot import components inside the lib which were coded in the project.